# Getting property description attribute

Tags: c#

**Existing code (simplified)**

I have this function

```
public static string[] GetFieldNames<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
  where T : class
{
  var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => SystemTypes.Contains(p.PropertyType)); // Only get System types

  return properties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
}
```

So if say I have this class

```
class MyClass {
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Description("The value")]
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I can have code like this

```
List<MyClass> items = ...; // Populate items somehow
string[] fieldNames = GetFieldNames(items); // This returns ["Name", "Value"]
```

That works fine.

**The problem**

I need to get the Description (if it exists), so that `GetFieldNames(items)` returns `["Name", "The value"]`

How do I modify the `GetFieldNames()` function to read the Description attribute if it exists?
<sub>(Please note that this function has been simplified, the real function is much more complex, so please avoid changing the logic)</sub>

Comment: What is it returning now, and what do you need to be done differently? Do you want to return a `Dictionary` instead of a string array?

Comment: McAdams331, have you read the question? I'm not sure how I can make it clearer. No, it will still be a string array (the function signature shouldn't change)

Comment: Where can I find SystemTypes class you're using??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
return properties.Select(p => 
    Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) ? 
        (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute).Description:
        p.Name
    ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE: just add `using System.Reflection` as `GetCustomAttribute` is an extension method in .Net 4.5**

```
public static Tuple<string,string>[] GetFieldNames<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
{
    var result =
        typeof (T).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => SystemTypes.Contains(p.PropertyType) &&p.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>() != null)
            .Select(
                p =>
                    new Tuple<string, string>(p.Name,
                        p.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

for earlier version of .Net framework we can use this extension method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this System.Reflection.MemberInfo mi) where T : Attribute
    {
        return mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (T),true).FirstOrDefault() as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty, but there is an error: 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute'

Comment: `GetCustomAttribute` is an extension method in `System.Reflection` in .Net 4.5 and higher

Answer (score 4):

This is a generic function you can make use of, if the `fieldName` has `description` tag attribute it return the value otherwise it return `null`.

```
public string GetDescription<T>(string fieldName)
{
    string result;
    FieldInfo fi = typeof(T).GetField(fieldName.ToString());
    if (fi != null)
    {
        try
        {
            object[] descriptionAttrs = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            DescriptionAttribute description = (DescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttrs[0];
            result = (description.Description);
        }
        catch
        {
            result = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
class MyClass {
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Description("The age description")]
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

string ageDescription = GetDescription<MyClass>(nameof(Age));
console.log(ageDescription) // OUTPUT: The age description
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using `Description` attribute a lot so I wrote [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProductivityTools.DescriptionValue/) for this purpose.

With it you could just call:

```
typeof(TestClass).GetPropertyDescription("PropertyName");
```

It also allows to take `DescriptionAttribute` from class, field, enum and method.

Answer (score 0):

use GetCustomAttributes Method

```
static void attributecheck()
{
    var props = typeof(Product).GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        var att = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true);
        if (att.Length >0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```